# PCL viewer->spinOnce() makes QT application quit

Tags: qt, point-cloud-library

I have a QT C++ application that calls a non-QT function that runs a PCL code base on this example http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/interactive_icp.php. Everything works OK, but when the PCL code finishes (PCLVisualizer closes and returns to the QT code), the QT application automatically quits.

I have checked what instruction causes this error, and turns out it is the call to `PCLVisualizer::spineOnce()`. If I comment such line, the PCL visualizer does not show correctly but the point cloud operations do run OK, and when the computation is completed QT does not crash.

I was wondering why the call to `PCLVisualizer::spineOnce()` is causing such behavior? Why is my QT application crashing if I call such function in my PCL code?

This is the call the PCL function from a QT SLOT function

```
void face_processing_GUI::runAlignment()
{
    icp::run_icp(target, source);
}
```

And the PCL `icp::run_icp(string, string)` function could be as simple as

```
int icp::run_icp(std::string in_target, std::string in_source)
{
    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer  * viewer = new  pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer("ICP stage");
    viewer->spinOnce(); // If I comment this time it does NOT crash
    viewer->close();
    delete viewer;
}
```

Comment: Is it quit and/or crash? If it is a crash, what does the backtrace say?

Comment: I don't think it is a crash, Output in debugging mode is here http://pastebin.com/9JkcuaTU

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the `viewer->close()` after the `viewer->spinOnce()` I don't think it's supposed to run like that, the `spinOnce()` method should run in a loop; otherwise you should use `spin()`. Could you try this? I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment.

```
//Main loop
while ( !viewer->wasStopped())
{
    viewer->spinOnce(100);
    // Comment this line if you don't use another thread to run the visualizer.
    boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::microseconds (100000)); 
}
```

It also might be better if you created the viewer using a shared pointer form the boost library

```
boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer (new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer ("3D Viewer"));
```

Comment: I will try that, thanks. However, how can I automatically close the `PCLVisualizer` without using `close()`? I am interested in showing the viewer for a fixed number of iterations and then close it. How can I trigger what `wasStopped()` required, automatically? I believe `wasStopped()` looks for events such as key 'q' or Esc pressed?

Comment: @Dan Is it working when you stop it manually?  You can use viewer->spin();  viewer->close();

Comment: Sorry for late reply! Your suggestion does not change anything, it still crashes when I use the `viewer->spinOnce(100)`. The only way QT does not crash is if I comment out this line, however then the viewer is useless :(